# Monotouch and sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, xamarin.ios

Here's the scenario: I have created a db3 file, attached it to to the solution, changed it to content (tried resource as well), and copying all the time. When I launch the app, I copy this to the document folder of the app. Now, it works flawlessly in the simulator, i.e. I can both read and write. But on the device, it's only in Read-Only mode. How do I make it writable on the device? I am using the latest ios 5 and latest monotouch.

Thanks in advance for any help. 
And Merry Christmas everyone :)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're opening the DB you copied to the document's folder? Let the app spit out the path of the DB you're opening. I suspect you're trying to access the one of the app bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check and get back soon. I was in tunnel vision mode, lol.

Comment: You are right indeed. I forgot to include the path to the document folder when creating the connection. You can put that in post, I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files stored in the .app directory are read-only on device.

If you need to have a read-write version of any of your data files, you need to copy this to your Documents storage area.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I made the mistake that Krumelur pointed out. BTW, I have found a lot of answers from your posts. Thanks a bunch again and Merry Christmas.